# Typescript how to write nested object types with non-static keys

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this, lets call `theObject` variable

```
         {
            "activate": {
                "from": "pending",
                "to": "active"
            },
            "deactivate": {
                "from": ["pending", "active"],
                "to": "inactive"
            }
        };
```

and example code like this

```
class Test {
   constructor(data : Object)
}

const test = new Test(theObject);
```

The code isn't returning any error since the type is correct. But I want more deep type interface for `theObject`.
The list of objects within `theObject` can be anything and more, like this for example :

```
{
            "darkKnight": { // the key should be in string
                "from": "bruceWayne", // from should be string or array of string
                "to": "batman" // to should be string
            },
            "theAmazing": {
                "from": ["peterParker", "milesMorales"],
                "to": "spiderMan"
            },
            "manOfSteel": {
                "from": "clackKent",
                "to": "superman"
            }
        };
```

The question is, how to write the more deep type definition interface for `theObject`, rather than using `Object` type

Comment: You can use either [Object Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) or [Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) along with [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your samples a fitting interface could look somewhat like this:

```
interface ObjectType {
    [key: string]: { from: string | string[]; to: string; }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgCoCeADigN4CwAUMjcgNoDWEBAXMgM5hSgDmAum1LIYUAPYBbNp24geyAD4cuvOnwDcyMKLYBlZbI0BfKscpUEokJ2SisbDNlyESyALzIK1Wt+8AiACZwUAwA0iDAPAAWYL6CyAD08ZqRKEwEHJGiAK4ANv7I6CigSjI8VD4VPr4iErHIvuhQWUgA6nAEIBC+ADQJSTXiGdl5BSjSvDZQyEFQ7TYwJbzllSu+WnUNcGDicCC+fZqiQ7n5hYuyyys0ht2XV2spAII7AF68dZ5XldVi4nV0vhIkCgAAUgkwoD16uJgDkIOwALKiWZw9i+Pi3LxfPzrNi+dhEYD+aAI3a+O4rG4U747ECoGB6CAQHIfalfH61PEIHKIUIQcA9Nn3XH1dhZEhQWnkrFXUyUtRAA)

Comment: I thought that interface only applicable if the object only contain one key. Thank you.